# Get the ID from a button which has a dynamic ID

Tags: ajax

I can not grasp my mind around this.

I am making a ajax call into a servlet. The problem is, on the page that is displayed, i could have 1-20 different buttons that needs to recall the same servlet. So I have the following form...

```
<form id="ajax-contact">
    <input type="text" value="${item.transactionId}" id="transactionId" name="transactionId"/><br>
    <input type="text" value="deliveryReceipt" id="action" name="action"/><br>
    <input type="text" value="${item.id}" id="id" name="id"/><br>
    <button type="submit" id="${item.id}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".${item.id}">view delivery receipt</button>
</form>
```

In my ajax, I have this...

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        //var formData = $(form).serialize();
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var tranid = $("#transactionId").val();
        var action = $("#action").val();

        var dataFromForm = "trannsactionId="+tranid+"&action="+action+"&id="+id;
        alert(dataFromForm);
        alert(formData);
        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            url : "Controller",
            type: "GET",
            data : dataFromForm,
            dataType: "json",
        })
        .success(function(response) {
...
```

I am trying to make it so the ajax call uses the params for the specific set of information within the form. How can I do this?

Thanks!

More detail:
Once this page shows, if I have 10 sections on there with a button. When I click on the first view delivery receipt button, it works fine.

If I go down my list and click on t he 8th view delivery receipt, itll make an ajax call for the first form.

Comment: Did you try with  ` var str = $( "#ajax-contact" ).serialize(); ` ?

Comment: @executable yes, you can see i have a line of code commented out. var formData = $(form).serialize();. i used this wehre I have data: in the ajax call

Comment: so right now, if i go down my list...and say i click on the fifth button..itll make the call for the FIRST set it finds...

Comment: Can you please inspect the DOM before you submit the form to make sure the value for each input is what you expect? Also, in var dataFromForm, "trannsactionId" should be "transactionId" I presume?

Comment: yes it should...doesnt make a difference though...

Comment: and the value for every input is correct. the button is, when i click on the button to submit my form, its looking for ajax-contact. and since every form has ajax-contact, when it finds the first one, thats the one it uses. im not sure how to make the id of very form dynamic and then find that with ajax before i start my call.